# How to rotate a line shape 90 Degrees?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am going to have a form with 60 Line Shapes (Using Visual Studios PowerPack). I would like the user to be able to rotate the shapes 90 Degrees using the left and right buttons on the keyboard.

What would be the best way to do this? I have tried other methods however this amounts to 1000's of lines of code, I am still learning and I want to know the best practices.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Depends on how your line are stored (coordinate or image). If you just want to flip 90 degrees, you could just switch x and y. (clockwise or counter-clockwise?)

Comment: It would help to see some sample code that demonstrates how at least one line is used on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming for the moment that you've already written the part to handle the geometry once, and are asking about how to re-use the code, without duplicating it for 60 lines. This matters because it's not 100% clear from the question whether you're rotating around the mid-point or around the starting point, as the LineShape type does make a distinction between the Starting and Ending points. Without that information, I can't write the geometry code for you.

The first part isn't so bad. We just setup a few methods that can handle rotating any line:

```
'Note that rotating a line 90 degrees around it's midpoint
' will give the same result whether you go clockwise or counterclockwise,
' but I figure you'll want to adapt this for other shapes later, or that
' you're rotating around the line's starting point

Private Sub RotateClockwise(ByVal line As LineShape) 
    'Code to rotate the passed line clockwise here
     Dim x1 As Integer = line.X1
     Dim y1 As Integer = line.Y1
     Dim x2 As Integer = line.X2
     Dim y2 As Integer = line.Y2


End Sub

Private Sub RotateCounterclockwise(ByVal line As LineShape) 

    'Code to rotate the passed line counter-clockwise here

End Sub

Private Sub LineShape_KeyDown(Byval sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)
    'Which line?
    Dim line As LineShape = TryCast(sender, LineShape)
    If line Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    'Left key?
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then RotateCounterclockwise(line)

    'Right key?
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then RotateClockwise(line)
End Sub
```

This is where it gets tricky. Notice that the event handler above is missing the `Handles` keyword. We want to hookup the `KeyDown` event handler for *all* of your LineShape controls to this one method. This will be a bit repetitive, as it means one additional line of code for each line on your form, but it's better than needing to write the above code for *all* of your lines:

```
Dim Lines As New List(Of LineShape)()
Lines.Add(LineShape1)
Lines.Add(LineShape2)
'...
Lines.Add(LineShape60)
For Each Line As LineShape In Lines
     AddHandler Line.KeyDown, AddressOf LineShape_KeyDown
Next
```

That code goes in your form's constructor *after* the `InitializeComponent()` method.

I could do better still if the LineShape type were a true control (`For EAch Line In Me.Controls.OfType(Of LineShape)()`), but the docs show this is actually a `Component`, and not a `Control`.

Comment: Hello, I haven't added any code for the lines geometry, sorry for the confusion. I would ideally like to be able to rotate the line 90 degrees by its midpoint if possible. Thanks for your help I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: It is worth noting here that it is important to remove the handlers in the form's disposing code.  Un-removed handlers will pin those objects and prevent GC.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can subclass `LineShape` and build "rotatability" into your new class as :

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks
Public Class MySmartLine
    Inherits LineShape
    Private Sub RotateClockwise()
        'Code to rotate clockwise here
        Me.X1 = ...
        Me.X2 = ...
    End Sub
    Private Sub RotateAntiClockwise()
        'Code to rotate anti clockwise here
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyDown(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnKeyDown(e)
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then
             RotateAntiClockwise()
        End If
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
             RotateClockwise()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

After building your project, a custom `MySmartLine` component will appear in your toolbox and you can use it in place of `LineShape`.